# Android. Layout item move to right side

Tags: android, layout

I have android layout with three parts (imageview, textview, imageview) and I want the last part move to right side, now its near the second element.

My code:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menuItemDesc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemIconRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menuItemDesc"
        android:gravity="right" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check out `RelativeLayouts` and the `android:alignParentRight="true"` or you can play with LinearLayout's `weight` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `TextView` the following attributes:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will make the TextView stretch to use up the space between the two `ImageView`s. The other alternative is to use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, but this should work for your needs.

Comment: May also need/want to get rid of `layout_weight="0.1"` on the second ImageView to avoid any weirdness there